# Creating a multilevel hash from a list of hashes

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a sub that can take a list of hashes and create a nested list based on the contents of an arbitrary number of fields.  I just can't get the recursion setup correctly. I'm getting a bunch of bug data out of a database and want to group the data on an arbitrary list of fields (team, priority, etc).  I really don't have any example code that I think is even getting close enough

Example below

I have the following DS:

```
$ds =
[
  {
    foo => 'A',
    bar => 'B',
    baz => 'C',
  },
  {
    foo => 'A',
    bar => 'B',
    baz => 'F',
  },
  {
    foo => 'A',
    bar => 'D',
    baz => 'G',
  },
  {
    foo => 'R',
    bar => 'J',
    baz => 'G',
  }
]
```

Given the following function call

```
# prototype   groupBy(data, field-1,field-2,field-n)
groupBy($ds,'foo','bar');
```

I want the following output

```
$res = {
         A => {
                B => [
                       {
                         foo => 'A',
                         bar => 'B', 
                         baz => 'C',
                       }, 
                       {
                         foo => 'A',
                         bar => 'B',
                         baz => 'F',
                       }
                     ],
                D => [
                       {
                         foo => 'A',
                         bar => 'D',
                         baz => 'G', 
                       }
                     ],
              },
         R => {
                J => [
                       {
                          foo => 'R',
                          bar => 'J',
                          baz => 'G',
                       }
              }

        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite straightforward using a recursive approach

The following code demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $ds = [
  { bar => "B", baz => "C", foo => "A" },
  { bar => "B", baz => "F", foo => "A" },
  { bar => "D", baz => "G", foo => "A" },
  { bar => "J", baz => "G", foo => "R" },
];

my $grouped = groupBy($ds, qw/ foo bar /);

use Data::Dump;
dd $grouped;

sub groupBy {

  my ($ds, $key, @rest) = @_;
  return $ds unless $key;

  my %groups;
  push @{ $groups{$_->{$key}} }, $_ for @$ds;
  $groups{$_} = groupBy($groups{$_}, @rest) for keys %groups;

  return \%groups;
}
```

**output**

```
{
  A => {
         B => [
                { bar => "B", baz => "C", foo => "A" },
                { bar => "B", baz => "F", foo => "A" },
              ],
         D => [{ bar => "D", baz => "G", foo => "A" }],
       },
  R => { J => [{ bar => "J", baz => "G", foo => "R" }] },
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Was being dense.  I like the use of the \@rest that shortens \@rest and pulls key on the recursive call.  clever.

Answer (score 0):

The hard coded solution:

```
my $res;
for (@$ds) {
   push @{ $res->{ $_->{foo} }{ $_->{bar} } }, $_;
}
```

But you want to support a variable-length list of keys. Just add a bit of looping.

```
sub groupBy {
    my ($ds, @keys) = @_;
    my $res;
    for (@$ds) {
       my $p = dive($res, @$_{ @keys });
       push @$$p, $_;
    }
   return $res;
}
```

where `dive` is either

```
sub dive {
   my $p = \shift;
   $p = \( $$p->{$_} ) for @_;
   return $p;
}
```

or

```
use Data::Diver qw( DiveRef );
sub dive {
   $_[0] //= {};
   return DiveRef(shift, map \$_, @_);
}
```